# Dataframe Resample with GroupBy on time data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, resampling

Traffic data per second shows the number of cars in and out. I want to aggregate them into 2-minute by In/Out and show their totals, like:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'time': ["13:34:16","13:34:19","13:34:52","13:34:55","13:34:58","13:35:01","13:35:04","13:35:37","13:35:40","13:35:43","13:36:37","13:36:39","13:36:43","13:36:46","13:36:49","13:36:52","13:36:58","13:37:04","13:37:07","13:37:13","13:37:46","13:37:49","13:37:58",], 
'cars' : [15,22,12,1,331,32,14,5,51,13,3,22,5,2,4,1,3,5,89,105,1,63,1,],
'flow': ["In","Out","In","Unknown","Out","In","Out","Unknown","Out","Out","In","In","Unknown","In","In","Out","In","In","In","In","In","In","In",]}
```

I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.time = '2020-01-23 ' + df.time     # data date

df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, unit='s')

print (df.groupby('flow').resample('2T')['cars'].sum())
```

But it gives error:

```
ValueError: non convertible value 2020-01-23 13:34:16 with the unit 's'
```

What is the right way to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should resample on index. Can you try:

```
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time)
df.set_index("time").groupby('flow').resample('2T')['cars'].sum()
flow     time               
In       2020-01-23 13:34:00     59
         2020-01-23 13:36:00    298
Out      2020-01-23 13:34:00    431
         2020-01-23 13:36:00      1
Unknown  2020-01-23 13:34:00      6
         2020-01-23 13:36:00      5
Name: cars, dtype: int64
```

And further if you wish to replicate your excel:

```
df_new = df_new.unstack().T
df_new["Total"] =df_new.sum(axis=1)
print(df_new)
flow                  In  Out  Unknown  Total
time                                         
2020-01-23 13:34:00   59  431        6    496
2020-01-23 13:36:00  298    1        5    304
```